# JavaScript error on IE 8 while trying to comment on one of my questions

Tags: support

The question is:

[Exception in method signature in interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394361/exception-in-method-signature-in-interface)

Browser details:

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; 
  Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; 
  .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)

Timestamp: Tue, 1 May 2012 06:42:40 UTC
```

Webpage error details:

```
Message: Expected ';'
Line: 132
Char: 54
Code: 0
URI: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=567d506f2223
```

Anyone else seeing this? Is it a bug or a problem with my browser/cache/extensions? CDN caching issue?

Comment: What part "does not work"?

Comment: @The Establishment, the part that should open the edit box after pressing 'add comment'

Comment: Looks like you can add comments just fine here... Keep in mind that there is no `@downvoter`, and that [downvotes work differently on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: @The Establishment, where to drop snagit capture?

Comment: Most people put that stuff in their question. Are you sure that you've read the [FAQ]?

Comment: @The Establishment, yesiamsure. See my edits

Comment: Is this still happening? Can you post comments on other posts? Can you post comments when using different browser?

Comment: can you try nuking your cache?

Comment: also ... just a shot in the dark, we have done no testing on hebrew IE, it is possible this is a local issue

Comment: @waffles, tried Chrome, FF and IE. same error. Cleareing the cache does not help. My OS and browser locale is en-U, no Hebrew involved

Comment: Funny how aviad has no problem here with comments apparently. Build numbers on meta & SO are different right now.

Comment: @aviad maybe we have a poison entry in the cdn, can you do a diff comparing http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=567d506f2223 with http://sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=567d506f2223 ?

Comment: also @aviad are you behind any kind of proxy?

Comment: @waffles, i am (corporate policy), but I checked it also without a proxy and the effect is the same.